# Regex match and substring in one?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a HTML source as input and would like to know what CMS the website is made in.
Many CMS leave their name in a meta tag like this:

```
<meta name="Generator" content="MY CMS" />
```

I can get the result like this:

```
        Match match = Regex.Match(html, ".*(?i)meta.*generator.*");
        match = Regex.Match(match.ToString(), "content.*\".*\"");
        match = Regex.Match(match.ToString(), "\".*\"");
```

Gives me "MY CMS"

But is there any way to shorten it down to one Regex.Match?

Please notice, that the meta tag could be like this:

```
<meta content="MY CMS" name="Generator" />
```

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Or you could use the right tool for the job: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: avoid `regex`...use html parser like htmlagilitypack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<meta[^>]+content\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]+)['"][^>]*>");
Match match = regex.Match(input);
```

The value is in group 1.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<meta\s+name=""Generator""\s+content=""([^""]+)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Match(html);
var generator = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not a good choice for parsing HTML files..

HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format..

Use [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Regex is used for **Regular** expression NOT **Irregular** expression

You can use this code to retrieve it using `HtmlAgilityPack`

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var content= doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='Generator']")
                .Attributes["content"].Value;
```